# Dynamically assign source to image in WPF DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

In my window, I am using a template selector, and within this, I have a number of images in the templates. What I need to do, is dynamically assign the source of an image when the page is loaded as it is dependent on other values as to what the image is, but I can't seem to access the image within the template.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:UIDataTemplateSelector x:Key="UITemplateSelector" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Modern">
        <Button Name="WindowIconImage_" 
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                MaxHeight="48" 
                MaxWidth="48" 
                Width="48" 
                Height="48">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Name="WindowIconImage" 
                           IsEnabled="False" 
                           IsHitTestVisible="False"/>                                 
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

From here I want to set the image to a value I get in my code, at the moment I am left with

```
Set(ByVal value As System.Windows.Media.ImageSource)
        WindowIconImage.Source = value
    End Set
```

I have tried various methods but I am unable to extract the value to assign. Any hints as to how I could go about this? I've attempted a direct cast to the button or image without it being in a button but still having no luck

My template selector:

```
Namespace UIDataSelector
Public Class UIDataTemplateSelector
    Inherits DataTemplateSelector

    Public uiVersion As String

    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(ByVal item As Object, ByVal container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate

        Dim element As FrameworkElement = TryCast(container, FrameworkElement)

        If element IsNot Nothing AndAlso item IsNot Nothing Then
            uiVersion = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xxx")

            If uiVersion = "Classic" Then
                Return TryCast(element.FindResource("ClassicTemplate"), DataTemplate)
            ElseIf uiVersion = "Modern" Then
                Return TryCast(element.FindResource("ModernTemplate"), DataTemplate)
            End If
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Are you using data binding? That's the key to configure data templates. Accessing view elements from a data template in code is a pain!

Comment: I think I've gone really wrong somewhere - this is all new to me so muddling my way through. So what I really want to be doing, is have a grid that I bind either of the two selected templates to, which I feel may partially solve this other issue that I am having? If I was to have a grid, how would I bind the selected template from the selector to it?

Comment: Could you also show the code that uses the template selector?

Comment: Added it - I'm not sure if that's where I've gone wrong

Comment: Ok, are you using the template selector somewhere in XAML?

Comment: <local:UIDataTemplateSelector x:Key="UITemplateSelector" /> I have that line in my template above, but now I think of it, should that be out of the template selector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150797/discussion-between-navvy-and-jandotnet).